# Create routes on dynamic menu bar in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I want to implement the navigation on menu bar which I am fetching from api. For e.g. on home page I have four menus like menu1 menu2 menu3 menu4 which displays always. On click on these menus i want to fetch products related to them.

I have read about nested routes in React js but unable to implement that.

Dynamic menu bar of categories:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Api from '../../Api';

class TopMenu extends React.Component {
    state = {
        categories : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        Api.get(`categories`).then(
            response => {
                this.setState({categories: response.data});
            });
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="menu">
                {this.state.categories.map(category => (
                    <Link to={"/category/" + category.name} key={category.id} className="menu-item"><span>{category.name}</span></Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default TopMenu;
```

My Routes file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import CategoryProducts from './CategoryProducts';
import Home from './Home';

const Routes = () => {
    return(
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/category/:name' component={CategoryProducts} />
        </Switch>
    );
};

export default Routes;
```

The click on Category will just change the browser url, not the page.

CategoryProducts.ja

```
import React from 'react';
import Products from './Products';

class CategoryProducts extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="content-wrapper">
                <div className="menu-left">
                    <Products/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CategoryProducts;
```

Products.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Api from './Api'
import Card from './components/Card';

class Products extends React.Component {
    state = {
        categories : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let categoryName = this.props.match ? this.props.match.params.name : 'Veg Pizza';
        Api.get(`category/${categoryName}`).then(
            response => {
                this.setState({products: response.data});
            });
    };


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="ref">
                    <div className="menu-hr"></div>
                    <div className="menu-cat">
                        <div className="menu-catname ">BESTSELLERS</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-container">
                    <div className="all-cards" data-label="Bestsellers">
                        <Card />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Products;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Products component is not mounting again and again, because this renders on all possible categories. Therefore In order to fetch data for different categories, you might have to use *componentDidUpdate* lifecycle method.

```js
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Api from './Api'
import Card from './components/Card';

class Products extends React.Component {
    state = {
        categories : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let categoryName = this.props.match ? this.props.match.params.name : 'Veg Pizza';
        Api.get(`category/${categoryName}`).then(
            response => {
                this.setState({products: response.data});
            });
    };
    
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      if(prevProps.match.params.name !== this.props.match.params.name){
      Api.get(`category/${categoryName}`).then(
            response => {
                this.setState({products: response.data});
            });
      }
    
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="ref">
                    <div className="menu-hr"></div>
                    <div className="menu-cat">
                        <div className="menu-catname ">BESTSELLERS</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-container">
                    <div className="all-cards" data-label="Bestsellers">
                        <Card />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Products;
```

If you want to force rerenders anyway and componentDidUpdate doesnt works for you, you can cause force rerender using key prop

```js
import React from 'react';
import Products from './Products';

class CategoryProducts extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="content-wrapper">
                <div className="menu-left">
                    <Products key={this.props.match.params.name}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CategoryProducts;
```

Please let me know if ut didnt solve your problem.

Comment: Tried both approaches. But it still didnt solve my problem. First approach throwing the error "Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" and second one also didnt work. I have one more problem here, while checking your second approach, I have console.log the this.props.match.params.name in CategoryProducts, It displays twice when I click on category links

Comment: @SamGeeks can you pleae host a sandbox so that it is easier to work with.